# Does Ruby on Rails have read stream for files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-io, stream

Does rails have a way to implement read streams like Node js for file reading?

i.e.

```
fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/data.txt');
```

as apposed to

```
fs.readFile(__dirname + '/data.txt');
```

Where I see ruby has

```
file = File.new("data.txt")
```

I am unsure of the equivalent in ruby/rails for creating a stream and would like to know if this is possible. The reasons I ask is for memory management as a stream will be delivered piece by piece as apposed to one whole file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to read a file in Ruby piece-by-piece, there are a host of methods available to you.

- [`IO#each_line`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html#method-i-each_line)/[`IO::foreach`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html#method-c-foreach), also implemented in `File` to iterate over each line of the file. Neither reads the whole file into memory; instead, both simply read up until the next newline, return, and pause reading, barring a possible buffer.
- [`IO#read`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html#method-i-read)/[`IO::read`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html#method-c-read) takes a `length` parameter, which allows you to specify for it to read up to `length` bytes from the file. This will only read that many, and not the whole thing.
- [`IO::binread`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html#method-c-binread) does the same as `IO::read`, but will open the file in binary mode.
- [`IO#readpartial`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html#method-i-readpartial) appears to be very similar or identical to `IO#read`, but is also worth looking at.
- [`IO#getc`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html#method-i-getc) and [`IO#gets`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html#method-i-gets) both read from the file until they reach the end of what they'll return, as far as I can tell.

There are several more that I'm looking for right now.

Comment: I'm guessing node delivers in packet sizes (depending on what you specify), I'd also like to know if Ruby does the same somehow...

Comment: @Ruegen See the updated answer. There's an optional parameter to `read` to read a certain number of bytes.

Comment: thanks, I'll do some research in this area - it would be nice to know how easily this is implemented and how often it is used by developers as a standard way to doing this.

Comment: @Ruegen I've added a few more options again. If my answer helped, please upvote/accept!

Comment: Why `foreach` is not an instance method - so we can use it on `STDIN`, `StringIO`, etc.